# zend expressive custom configuration key

Tags: configuration, zend-framework2, mezzio

How to properly create a custom configuration key in zend expressive
I tried to create a file custom-config.php in the config/autoload directory but the key is not read by the container

my custom-config.php looks like this

```
<?php
[
    'customkey' => [
    'value1' => '1',
    'value2' => '2',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you a missing a `return` statement.

Try with

```
<?php

return [
    'customkey' => [
        'value1' => '1',
        'value2' => '2',
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides missing `return` statement, as  *marcosh* pointed out, I think additional problem is the filename itself.

It should be something like `custom-config.local.php` or `custom-config.global.php`.

Comment: I corrected both the file name and the return statement so it's reading the config file fine now. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Configuration files are loaded in a specific order. First `global.php`, then `*.global.php`, `local.php` and finally `*.local.php`. This way local settings overwrite global settings.

Settings shared between servers go into `*.global.php`, sensitive data and local settings in `*.local.php`. Local config files are ignored by git.

The default loading behavior is set in `config/config.php` if you want to change this.

Your custom config could look like this:

```
<?php // config/autoload/custom-config.global.php

return [
    'dependencies' => [
        'invokables' => [
            // ...
        ],
        'factories' => [
            // ...
        ],
    ],
    // Prefered format
    'vendor' => [
        'package' => [
            'key' => 'value',
        ]
    ],
    // Custom package
    'custom_package' => [
        'value1' => '1',
        'value2' => '2',
    ],
];
```